# Variable variable string constructed for "$GLOBALS" works within global scope, but not function scope

Tags: php, global-variables

> **An important note**: `$GLOBALS` are dirty and evil. Don't use them. Ever. Never ever ever.
>   Please focus on *the fact that it doesn't work* and not why you would be doing this in the first place, it is purely a theoretical question about a technical exercise.

This is a rather weird one. I'm attempting to construct a variable variable using a string named `$GLOBALS`.

**From the global scope**

Let's see what we get when `var_dump()`ing this in the global scope.

```
$g = sprintf('%s%s%s%s%s%s%s', chr(71), chr(76), chr(79), chr(66), chr(65), chr(76), chr(83));
var_dump($$g);
```

The result is an array of global variables, which you can see [here](http://codepad.org/EzPGGni10). Great! So, let's try this in a function.

**From a function scope**

First, let's just make sure that we can actually run an `$GLOBALS` check within a function.

```
function globalAllTheThings()
{
    var_dump($GLOBALS);
}

globalAllTheThings();
```

The result is: *it works*!! You can see this [here](http://codepad.org/LTvMm2qy).

Now, let's try the first test that we used in the global scope, within the function, and see what happens.

```
function globalAllTheThings()
{
    $g = sprintf('%s%s%s%s%s%s%s', chr(71), chr(76), chr(79), chr(66), chr(65), chr(76), chr(83));
    var_dump($$g);
}

globalAllTheThings();
```

**For simplicity's sake**

You can also try this *without* the weird obfuscation (don't ask).

```
function globalAllTheThings()
{
    $g = 'GLOBALS';
    var_dump($$g);
}

globalAllTheThings();
```

It *returns `NULL`*. What's that about?? Why does it return `NULL`, and what can I do to get this working. Why, you ask? For educational purposes of course, and **for science**!

[image: ALL THE THINGS, SRSLY]

Comment: For simplicity's sake, can't you write `$g = 'GLOBALS'` instead of your weird `sprintf-chr`? It shouldn't influence the result. If it did, that'd be worth a whole 'nother question.

Comment: Because `${'string'}` looks for variable in given scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the manual says so:

> **Warning**
>
> Please note that variable variables cannot be used with PHP's Superglobal arrays within functions or class methods. The variable `$this` is also a special variable that cannot be referenced dynamically.
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

It's simply "special". PHP is "special". Superglobals don't play by the same rules as regular variables to begin with. Someone forgot to or decided against making them compatible with variable variables in functions. Period.

Comment: Wow, nice find. I did "RTFM" on this but must have missed that. What a fail.

Comment: ...where "special" is used in highly politically incorrect sense.

Comment: @Dave PHP is the language among programming languages which is mostly defined by its exceptions, not its rules... ;)

Comment: Why then code `$f = '_POST'; var_dump($$f);` works properly? _POST is also a superglobal.

Comment: I've tried this inside `eval()` (that is my sandbox): `$f = 'GLOBALS'; $h = '_POST'; var_dump($$f, $$h);` - and that produced: `NULL array(2) { ["code"]=> string(49) "$f = 'GLOBALS'; $h = '_POST'; var_dump($$f, $$h);" ["eval"]=> string(4) "test" } ` - i.e. it seems. inside eval, there is a third case of behavior (GLOBALS still does not work)

Comment: @Alma 1) `eval` is not a "sandbox", 2) it works: http://codepad.org/jC1VoE8C 3) it's about *scope inside functions*, `eval`d code is simply in the global scope.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort @deceze - this was an interesting one! :)

Comment: eval is not a sandbox, but I was using it (simple script to test code). And get the result: GLOBALS is not working while _POST is working. I'm not arguing that inside function context _POST is not working - I just noticed the third possible case in this matter.